# hasOwnProperty and ECMAScript 5 strict mode

Tags: javascript, strict, ecmascript-5, hasownproperty

I'm curious: anyone knows why the ECMAScript5 specification hasn't tightened more the predefined object prototype's properties in strict mode? For instance, it seems like there's no info regarding the way hasOwnProperty is defined. I've tried redefining it (and tested the code in FF4 beta) and I was able to get away with this. If I didn't do anything wrong, then this means that anyone can *still* redefine the Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty property and really screw all the code that relies on it for working property...

thoughts on this?

EDIT: a little more info as I dig through the spec...

As I've put in a comment below, you can't really change Object.prototype  in strict mode due to the metadata that was applied to it (Writable, Enumerable and Configurable are all set to false) and FF 4 beta (which I'm using to run my tests) does generate the exception.

thanks.

Comment: The question is: Are built-in objects sealed by default? I haven't dug into ES5 yet, so I don't know the answer to that question.

Comment: @Šime Vidas No, built-in objects aren't sealed by default. Their [[Extensible]] is set to `true`, so you can easily add properties to them (see section 15). AIUI, the goal was to keep ES object model flexible, only locking absolutely crucial parts (such as making global `undefined`, `NaN` and `Infinity` properties non-writable & non-configurable :))

Answer (score 3):

And? I can kill of everything on `Object.prototype` if I wanted to, don't include such code in your project/site, no do something better, find those idiots who are doing such things and make sure to kick'em in the balls.

I mean, I can even screw up any given Python (2.x) program by doing `True = False`.

You can never protect against idiots. Never. Try to educate or avoid them.

**EDIT**

To clarify the impossibility of this, if you encapsulate your script into an anonymous wrapper (as you should do if you use it with other code) the `"use strict"` will be local to your code.

That means, if the **evil idiot** code does not use strict mode on its own - and they won't... unless they are total idiots, which I'm not talking about here - they run in ES3 and your beautiful strictness doesn't even exist.

Comment: "Never argue with an idiot, they drag you down to their level and beat you with experience"

Comment: Well, not really. Looking at the spec, I see that Object.prototype has the following attributes: Writable: false, enumerable: false and configurable: false. I've also tried changing it and I've noticed that FF does generate an exception if you try to do that.

Comment: @Luis Guess I used the wrong wording, I can simply delete all properties from it, only the property `prototype` of `Object` cannot be overridden.

Comment: ok, understood it. Anyway, I'm still interested in knowing why the spec didn't go that far. is it important to have a prototype property? Yes, it is. Is it important to have some non-configurable, non-writable inherited properties like hasOwnProperty? I say yes, but I'm really curious to understand the rationale behind not forcing that behaviour.

Comment: @Luis No real idea why they didn't do all that, guess if they wanted to they would have needed to change ES3 and there is for sure code out there that relies on the fact that you can overwrite builtins... and sadly they really care about not breaking that code :/